# Git "failed to push some refs to..." with custom Git bridge

Tags: python, git, paramiko

I have been working on setting up a git server by using Paramiko to act as an SSH bridge for Git. I am able to clone my repository without issue, and even push changes up, however I get an annoying error message.

```
Pushing to git@localhost:/pckprojects/heyworld
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 262 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@localhost:/pckprojects/heyworld
     348dfdc..1c0468e  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@localhost:/pckprojects/heyworld'
```

My git's config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
    sharedRepository = all
[receive]
    denyNonFastForwards = false
    denyCurrentBranch = false
    denyDeletes = false
```

The odd thing is "master" actually does get updated, and I have no other branches in the repository. In addition, if I clone / push the repository from disk rather than via SSH, I don't see any errors.

Anyone have any thoughts on why I'm seeing this error?

Thanks...

EDIT:

Since it seems likely my issues are related to my SSH server, the main loop is below:

```
        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        while True:
            try:
                r_ready, w_ready, x_ready = select.select(
                    [channel, proc.stdout, proc.stderr], [proc.stdin], [])
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                print 'channel: ' + str(channel)
                print 'proc: ' + str(proc)

            if channel in r_ready and channel.recv_ready():
                data = channel.recv(128)
                if len(data) > 0:
                    print 'IN>channel ' + repr(data)
                    proc.stdin.write(data)
                else:
                    pass

            if proc.stdout in r_ready:  
                data = proc.stdout.read(1)
                channel.sendall(data)

            if proc.stderr in r_ready:

                data = proc.stdout.read(1)
                if len(data) > 0:
                    channel.sendall(data)

                else:
                    print "Encountered empty stderr, breaking"
                    break                       

        print 'will close'
        channel.shutdown(2)
        channel.close()
```

**More Information**

I thought it might be helpful to see the actual communication. This is at it appears on the server side, since the git client doesn't allow you to see nearly this much.

```
git-receive-pack /home/www/data/project/heyworld/

OUT >>
00721ee2436e45c80236878132dc87d9e9fee6a81de5 refs/heads/master\x00 report-status delete-refs side-band-64k ofs-delta\n0000

IN >>
00841ee2436e45c80236878132dc87d9e9fee6a81de5 6054b3358787bafd1d96c0fdfbf016d620ccdf09 refs/heads/master\x00 report-status side-band-64k0000

IN >>
PACK\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x96\x0ex\x9c\xa5\x8cM\x0e\xc2 \x14\x06\xf7\x9c\x82\x0b\xd8<(?\x8f\xc4\x18\xf7n\xbc\x02\xc2\x87%\x16\xdb4\xb8\xf0\xf66\xbd\x82\xcb\x99d\xa6o\x80\x846\xd9!)\x1b\x0b\xb1\r1$dO\x05\xa6\xb0\xa3@\x06%D<\xb2\x16k\xdc\xf0\xeeRa/F\x07c\x13\x93\x1e\x1d{V\xa3\xce\x89}\x0e\x08\x05p\x91U\x86\x15\xf1\xd3\xa7e\x93\xf7\xa9\xceu\x95\xb7\xda\x1a\xbe\xf2\xbc\x1e8\xbc\x0e\xbc>[\xac\xf3\x90\x96v\x91J\xfb`X\xb3V\xf2D\x96H\xec\xb6\xd5\xde\xf1\xc7B4,\xe2\x07\xff\x8aF\xba\xaf\x01x\x9c340031Q\xc8H\xaddP\xd8P\xfcmzGg\x8aY\xc4\x8e\xad\xb1<\xca\x1b\xa3\x93\xee\xbd\x05\x00\xa8\xb4\x0c\x9by\xd3\xfe\xa0C\x86fU\x18\xbe\xa5\x86\xac5*\xf7\x11\x89\x8b9$x\x9c\x0b\x8b\x9a\x10\xc6\x92\x9b\x9a\xcf\x05\x00\x0f\xb2\x02\xe6=\x12?\xde\x1f\x9a=v\x0c3c\xf66\xc6\xcc1y\xe4\xb8\xa0

OUT >>
0030\x01000eunpack ok\n009krf/ed/atr0000

CLOSE CONNECTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful user on the git mailing list took what he thought was a stab in the dark and got it right.

I wasn't returning the exit code, which Git expects on pushes. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, this could be a bunch of issues!

- My initial guess is that some permissions are not correct on the server and thus could not update some non-critical information
- Could also some other issues as well...

Couple quick questions/suggestions:

- Can you run the command manually successfully?
- Try adding the --verbose flag to the push command (ie. git push --verbose origin/master)

Adding the verbose flag might put you on the fast track to figuring out the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The above output is actually already using the verbose flag.

Permissions was one of my first thoughts too, but the SSH process is running as root, so that really can't be the problem.

I don't think there is an issue with the repository because working on it (cloning, pushing, pulling etc) works fine if I just use it as a file based source.

It is unfortunate how little information Git's verbose flag gives, since it really doesn't tell you anything useful.